# Javascript parse error on '\u2028' unicode character

Tags: javascript, unicode

Whenever I use the \u2028 character literal in my javascript source with the content type set to "text/html; charset=utf-8" I get a javascript parse errors.

Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>json</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    var string = '     ';
    </script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

If the `<meta http-equiv>` is left out everything works as expected. I've tested this on Safari and Firefox, both exhibit the same problem.

Any ideas on why this is happening and how to properly fix this (without removing the encoding)?

Edit:
After some more research, the specific problem was that the problem character was returned using JSONP. This was then interpreted by the browser, which reads u2028 as a newline and throws an error about an invalid newline in a string.

Comment: Where do you get the parse error?

Comment: On the line with `var string = ' ';`

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Yes, it's a feature of the JavaScript language, documented in the ECMAScript standard (3rd edition section 7.3), that the U+2028 and U+2029 characters count as line endings. Consequently a JavaScript parser will treat any unencoded U+2028/9 character in the same way as a newline. Since you can't put a newline inside a string literal, you get a syntax error.

This is an unfortunate oversight in the design of JSON: it is not actually a proper subset of JavaScript. Raw U+2028/9 characters are valid in string literals in JSON, and will be accepted by `JSON.parse`, but not so in JavaScript itself.

Hence it is only safe to generate JavaScript code using a JSON parser if you're sure it explicitly `\u`-escapes those characters. Some do, some don't; many `\u`-escape all non-ASCII characters, which avoids the problem.

Comment: This is very helpful. The fix is to escape the JSON, then parse client-side. For example, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9691611/print-valid-non-escaped-json-in-a-view-with-rails for Ruby/Rails tells you to do `$.parseJSON("#{j xyz.to_json}")` in a server-side template.

Comment: Even better: `JSON.parse(#{j.to_json.inspect})` will render it as a string with `\uXXXX` for any irregular characters.

Comment: You could insert the JSON into a script tag with its type set to "application/json". This should avoid parsing the UTF-8 text as JavaScript. After the page is loaded, the JSON can be parsed using `JSON.parse()` by passing the `innerHTML` of the script tag as a parameter.

Comment: Not sure I would call it an oversight in JSON as much as design flaw in Javascript; inclusion of these characters as linefeeds is strange and unexpected, and not done by other textual data formats. But as to JSON, while its origins are from Javascript subset, it hasn't been tied to Javascript for years, and specification does not claim that it would be a subset, or that this would be a goal. Recommendation is to NOT eval it, but properly parse. So it is not entirely clear that quoting writing is either necessary or even a good thing to do, except for JSONP usage.

Comment: Sure, it's a design flaw in JavaScript *and* an oversight in JSON. It was central to the original design of JSON that it be a JS subset potentially parsable with `eval`, and traces of this remain (eg see language in http://www.json.org/js.html). It's an understandable oversight, since the behaviour of U+2028–9 wasn't well-understood or consistently-implemented at the time (it was only properly specified with ECMAScript Third Edition in 1999, and back then in the Netscape/JavaScript vs IE/JScript days it wasn't even clear that ECMA was going to be considered definitive).

Comment: In the 10th edition (very new): "Updated syntax includes
... allowing U+2028 (LINE SEPARATOR) and U+2029 (PARAGRAPH
SEPARATOR) in string literals to align with JSON." from https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-262.pdf

Answer (score 11):

Alright,to answer my own question.

Normally a JSON parser strips out these problem characters, because I was retrieving JSONP I wasn't using a JSON parser, in stead the browser tried to parse the JSON itself as soon as the callback was called.

The only way to fix it was to make sure the server never returns these characters when requesting a JSONP resource.

p.s.
My question was about u2028, according to [Douglas Crockford's json2 library](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/4982ffbecf8175f233b0c9626bc8629c70faf5a2/json2.js#L371) all of the following characters can cause these problems:

'\u0000\u00ad\u0600-\u0604\u070f\u17b4\u17b5\u200c-\u200f\u2028-\u202f\u2060-\u206f\ufeff\ufff0-\uffff'

Comment: do you have a source for that list? (the link under douglas Crockford doesnt lead anywhere usefull)

Comment: Link into JSON-js which won't break when the repo/file is updated: https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/c98948ae1944a28e2e8ebc3717894e580aeaaa05/json2.js#L180-L181

Answer (score 2):

Could you just use `\u2028`, instead of real character?, because U+2028 is [unicode line seperator](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2028/index.htm), browsers would think that as real line break character like `\n`.

We cannot do like

```
x = "

"
```

Right? but we do `x = "\n"`, so might be same concept.

Comment: Douglas Crockford's JSON implementation does escape the string, but still throws the parse error. In Safari the native JSON implementation is used, which also throws the parse error.

We're loading jsonp so the browser will attempt to parse it before any other javascript has a chance to strip out any invalid characters. I will probably have to solve this server side.

Comment: Yeah @klaaspieter, probably on server side, and If you got to do that, also escape `\u2029` too

Comment: By the way, I've tested it some more, Douglas Crockford's implementation is *not* throwing the parse error.

Answer (score -5):

Well, that makes sense, since you are telling the browser that the HTML and script are both using UTF-8, but then you specify a character that is not UTF-8 encoded.  When you specify "charset=UTF-8", you are respoonsible for making sure the bytes transmitted to the browser are actually UTF-8.  The web server and and browser will not do it for you in this situation.

Comment: So, how to solve it? The character was entered by a user of the website. His data is stored in JSON. Every time I request the JSON I get a parse error, because the character is in there. I cannot just delete the character, because it's likely that the client will enter it again.

Comment: According to the comments for [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1811505/with-jquery-access-json-from-cross-domain-url-where-json-may-be-poorly-formed#1811737) answer, this is a valid UTF-8 character which should be correctly parsed.