# Decode Python encoding in Jquery ui autocomplete JSON

Tags: python, json, encoding, jquery-ui-autocomplete

My python function.json returns this:

```
[{"id": "187", "label": "H\xc3\xa1bitos"}]
```

The `label` is an encoding of `"Hábitos"`,

How can I get the proper label in Javascript?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965293/javascript-parse-error-on-u2028-unicode-character

Answer (score 0):

This *is* a proper UTF8 string and not some kind of "python encoding". You just need tn use UTF8 on your page and it will work.