# Print valid, non-escaped JSON in a view with Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I've tried everything.  Every combination of the helpers `raw`, `html_safe` `to_json` including some attempts with `::JSON.encode` and `CGI.unescape`.  The issue is that regardless of what I  do, I can't print well-formed JSON in a view.  It's always HTML escaped.

Here's the code in my view:

`var campaignData<%= "=" + (raw @campaign.to_json) if @campaign %>;`

In my case, it's always the quotes that are escaped as ".  I would just do a gsub on the quotes, but that is a terrible solution to what IMO ought to be a very simple, well documented use case.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The problem here is with the "=" string. As it's considered unsafe, it taints the other string.

You can probably do either:

```
raw("=" + @campaign.to_json)
```

or

```
"= #{@campaign.to_json}".html_safe
```

which are roughly the same.

Comment: This is unsafe. What if the json contains a string with a less-than? If you put this in a script tag, someone can inject a closing script tag and start a new one with arbitrary code. You need to wrap the json string in `json_escape`. However, that function has been broken until just recently (rails 4.1).

Comment: Yes, I too found that this did not work for me when @campaign == "<script>alert('pwn')</script>"

Answer (score 15):

Since ActiveSupport 2.3.3 you have been able to do `.as_json`

Answer (score 5):

Did you try `escape_javascript`?

Here is an example from the *.haml file, which I just added to test my answer.

```
:javascript
  var foo=$.parseJSON("#{j @albums.to_json}")
```

Where `j` is an short alias for `escape_javascript`.

Comment: Yea, that didn't work.  Right now I'm just manually printing each value that I need, which is an awful solution, but its the only way I've been able to make it work.

Comment: Could you paste here a bit of your escaped string? Also, which version of ruby and rails do you use? Just wondering what could be wrong with that

Comment: It was valid JSON, except the quotes were replaced with the HTML quote entity `&quot;`  Using Rails 3.2.1

Comment: This was the best solution for me. I already have a model that returns valid JSON, but characters like \u2028 won't parse if included in the bootstrapped HAML.

Answer (score 0):

Try this with [utility method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ERB/Util.html#method-c-html_escape)

```
var campaignData<%=h " =#{raw @campaign.to_json}" if @campaign %>;
```