# Strip ruby string of a specific control character

Tags: ruby

This is pretty simple: how do I strip a ruby string of a special character? Here's the character:
http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2028/index.htm

And here's the string, with the two special characters between the period and the ending quote:

```
"Each of the levels requires logic, skill, and brute force to crush the enemy.  "
```

I've unsuccessfully tried this:

```
string.gsub!(/[\x00-\x1F\x7F]/, '')
```

and `gsub("/\n/", "")`

I'm using ruby 1.9.3p125

Comment: \x1F  ^_    (Unit separator, Information separator one)  ...... go here http://donsnotes.com/tech/charsets/ascii.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out! `.gsub(/\u2028/, '')`

Comment: i almost posted that first, but didnt know if ruby could do that haha

Comment: If you were using version 1.8.6, you couldn't as it didn't have full Unicode support.

Answer (score 8):

`String#gsub` will work, but is more general and less efficient at this than [String#tr](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-tr)

```
irb> s ="Hello,\u2028 World; here's some ctrl [\1\2\3\4\5\6] chars"
=> "Hello,\u2028 World; here's some ctrl [\u0001\u0002\u0003\u0004\u0005\u0006] chars"

irb> s.tr("\u0000-\u001f\u007f\u2028",'')
=> "Hello, World; here's some ctrl [] chars"

require 'benchmark'
Benchmark.bm {|x|
  x.report('tr')   { 1_000_000.times{ s.tr("\u0000-\u001f\u007f\u2028",'') } }
  x.report('gsub') { 1_000_000.times{ s.gsub(/[\0-\x1f\x7f\u2028]/,'') } }
}

          user     system      total        real
tr    1.440000   0.000000   1.440000 (  1.448090)
gsub  4.110000   0.000000   4.110000 (  4.127100)
```