# React server-side rendering - window.initialState - how to prevent XSS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm passing my initial state to react like the below

```
window.__INITIAL_STATE__= ${JSON.stringify(initialState)}
```

I havent done anything to guard against XSS. so for example if one of the user submitted content has the below string.
`"<script>***</script> "`

this unfortunately breaks the script tag in the html source. it returns an error specifying `ILLEGAL TOKEN`

so i was thinking of using something like this on the server side.

```
${JSON.stringify(initialState).replace(/</g, '\\u003c')
```

it works for now , but is there a better way to handle passing of the initial state in such cases? does the regex provided above cover all potential vulnerabilities?

I was thinking of just passing a json object via an api or something if this could lead to problems.

Comment: why does initialState have a script element inside it?

Comment: You need to escape `\u2028\u2029` as well. http://stackoverflow.com/a/9168133/351705

Comment: @kinakuta - it contains user submitted content .. just wanted to ensure that xss is prevented

Comment: I understand what you're trying to prevent, but are you stating that you have a valid script element inside initialState?

Comment: @kinakuta - no valid script elements :). just lots of arrays of strings basically

Comment: @YuryTarabanko - thank you

Answer (score 1):

can [this](https://github.com/yahoo/serialize-javascript) solve your problem?

it works like `JSON.stringify` but automatically escaped dangerous character