# chrome consloe error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token"?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console.log

```
a = "Πότε να χρησιμοποιήσετε το X-VPN (Αρχικό όνομαFastLemon VPN Free) Όταν συνδέεστε σε ένα δημόσιο Wi-Fi hotspot, Όταν παίζετε παιχνίδια και χρειάζεστε ένα καλύτερο δίκτυο, Όταν κάνετε online αγορές με την πιστωτική σας κάρτα ή το Paypal, όταν επικεντρώνεστε σε πράγματα επιχειρήσεων"
```

I put this code  to chrome console, it's error like

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```

this string is Greek， how can I fix this？

Comment: The left separator characters seem to be the issue. There are 3 of them... between 1) `Free)` and `Όταν`, 2) `hotspot,` and `Όταν`, and 3) `δίκτυο,` and `Όταν`. [JSHint](http://jshint.com/) warns for each of them that "*This character may get silently deleted by one or more browsers.*"

Comment: [Javascript parse error on '\u2028' unicode character](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965293/javascript-parse-error-on-u2028-unicode-character) The error is because those characters are recognized as part of the language's syntax. If you'd like to keep them within the string value, they'll have to be escaped as `\u2028` within the literal.

Answer (score 1):

This is because special charater:
 ·  Middle dot  Alt + 249, Alt + 0183   ·    ·
in your string. You can replace Alt + 249 with · like:

```
a = "Πότε να χρησιμοποιήσετε το X-VPN (Αρχικό όνομαFastLemon VPN Free)&middot;Όταν συνδέεστε σε ένα δημόσιο Wi-Fi hotspot,&middot;Όταν παίζετε παιχνίδια και χρειάζεστε ένα καλύτερο δίκτυο,&middot;Όταν κάνετε online αγορές με την πιστωτική σας κάρτα ή το Paypal, όταν επικεντρώνεστε σε πράγματα επιχειρήσεων"
```

When show in HTML, html will convert to special character.
http://fontmeme.com/alt-codes-shortcuts-html-codes-for-special-characters/

Answer (score 0):

I find this error in chrome console, I select all the string, this red point is the error, I delete it then no error

[image: make it]

Comment: this string I get copy form google Sheets，my partner copy from page，then post to google Sheets, then I copy form Sheets，that red point appear