# Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token when retrieving JSON stringified object from SQLite (Cordova)

Tags: javascript, sqlite, cordova, ionic2, ionic3

(Ionic 3 app using SQLite)

I previously saved an object as a string using `JSON.stringify()`.  The JSON tests as valid in jsonlint.

When I am getting it out using a simple query `SELECT * FROM kv WHERE key = 'user'`, I get this error:

`VM432:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token`

The console shows it beginning here:
[image: Location of error]

I've been searching for a couple days trying to figure out what could cause this...  I've upgraded to the latest SQLite plugin in Ionic Native (3.12.1).  I've tried to remove all other items saved in this table - so I'm sure this particular `user` object is the culprit. It's quite large and contains sensitive data so I'm unable to post it here...

Shouldn't JSON.stringify() take care of any escaping that needs to be done for the string to be stored and retrieved?

Should I be examining that JSON object for odd characters?  Or does it look like the problem is elsewhere, given the location of the error?

Any tips are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

JSON.stringify is not capable of correcting the string content. Try pre processing the content which is pretty straightforward.

The problem is elsewhere - SQLite plugin- of course but eventually you need to handle it in your js code.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out there was a '\u2028' unicode character in the dataset, which Javascript does not handle well.  I had to clean these out.

More info here:

[Javascript parse error on '\u2028' unicode character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965293/javascript-parse-error-on-u2028-unicode-character)[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965293/javascript-parse-error-on-u2028-unicode-character)